# Change card's title without affecting the other element

Tags: javascript, html, selection, title

I want to change the card's title which is `Main Title` into `2nd Title` everytime the user selects an option in the dropdown.

Here's my code.

HTML:

```html
<h3 id="title" class="card-title">Main Title <span class="badge badge-primary" id="counts">0</span>
  <span class="float-right">
    <a href="" style="color: #c0c6cc;"><i 
    class="mdi mdi-trash-can"></i>
    </a>
    </span>
</h3>
<select class="form-control" id="select" onchange="optionCheck(this);" required>
  <option value="yor1" Option 1 </option>
    <option value="yor2">
      Option 2</option>
    <option value="yor3">
      Option 3</option>
</select>
```

If user select Option 3 the card's title change.

JS:

```js
function optionCheck(that) {
  if (that.value == "yor3") {
    alert("Title changed!");
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "2nd Title";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "Main title";
  }
}
```

Now the problem is if I select the Option1 or 2 only the Main title word can see the span badge and the icon disappears.

Comment: can you able to put **Main Title** in any span or div like <h3 id="title" class="card-title"><span>Main Title</span>

Answer (score 0):

Here is working code: https://jsfiddle.net/usmanmunir/c9uqktn3/19/

**HTML**

```
 <h3 id="title" class="card-title">Main Title</h3>
     <span class="badge badge-primary" id="counts">0</span>
      <span class="float-right">
        <a href="" style="color: #c0c6cc;">
        <i class="mdi mdi-trash-can"></i></a>
      </span>
    <br>
    <select class="form-control" id="select" onchange="optionCheck(this);" required>
      <option disabled selected></option>
      <option value="yor1">Option 1</option>
      <option value="yor2">Option 2</option>
      <option value="yor3">Option 3</option>
    </select>
```

**JS**

```
function optionCheck(that) {
  if (that.value === "yor1" || that.value === "yor2" || that.value === "yor3") {
      document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "2nd Title";
  } else {
      document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "Main title";
  }
}
```

Comment: my only problem is when selecting option 1 the span class of badge and the mdi icon disappear. It must not disappear cause I only need to change the text title.

Comment: I have updated the answer should be working now. Thanks for clarifying.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your content inside `span` and give that id `title` to the span tag so that only the content inside span will get changed.

**Demo code**:

```js
function optionCheck(that) {
  if (that.value == "yor3") {
    alert("Title changed!");
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "2nd Title";
  } else {
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML = "Main title";
  }
}
```

```html
   <!--added id to span tag-->
<h3 class="card-title"><span id="title">Main Title</span> <span class="badge badge-primary" id="counts">0</span>
  <span class="float-right">
<a href="" style="color: #c0c6cc;"><i 
class="mdi mdi-trash-can"></i>
</a>
</span>
</h3>
<select class="form-control" id="select" onchange="optionCheck(this);" required>
  <option value="yor1"> Option 1 </option>
    <option value="yor2">
      Option 2</option>
    <option value="yor3">
      Option 3</option>
</select>
```